# Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined data from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux-firebase

I am trying to git the totalBalance of but i face error Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined and in the same time i can iterate on the clients of the component the code is the below

```
//redux and firebase
import { useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { useFirestoreConnect, isLoaded, isEmpty} from 'react-redux-firebase'

const Clients = () => {

  useFirestoreConnect(["client"]) //the name of collection  on firebase

  const clients = useSelector((state) => state.firestore.ordered.client);

  const totalBalance = clients.reduce((acc,client)=>(acc + client.balance),0)
console.log(totalBalance);

  return (
    <div className="client">
      <div className="row client_head ">
      <div className="col">
      <FaUsers />
        <span className="ml-2">Clients</span>
      </div>
      <div className="col text-right">
      <span className="d-b">Total:  </span>
        <span className="ml-auto ">
        {clients.length===0?0:clients.reduce((acc,client)=>(acc + Number(client.balance),0))}
          </span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className="client_info row text-center">
          <table className="mt-3 w-100 table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>balance</th>
                <th>Details</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {clients.map(client => 
                <tr key={client.id}>
                  <td className="p-3">3</td>
                  <td>{client.firstName}</td>
                  <td>{client.lastName}</td>
                  <td>{client.email}</td>
                  <td>{client.balance}</td>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Clients
```

i thought the issue is clients is undefined but i don't know the reson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is telling you that the `clients` object which you are selecting from redux is `undefined`.  It might be that it starts out as `undefined` and then populates with the data asynchronously, so it would be `undefined` on the first render but fine afterwards.  If it is continuing to stay `undefined` then there is an issue somewhere else in your code.

There are two easy ways to deal with data that might not exist yet.

1. You can replace `undefined` with an empty array and render the rest of the component normally.  You would have a list with no items and 0 balance.

```
const clients = useSelector((state) => state.firestore.ordered.client) || [];
```

2. You can stop the rest of the component from rendering.  Either render nothing or a render some loading screen.

```
const clients = useSelector((state) => state.firestore.ordered.client);

if ( ! clients ) {
    return (<div>Loading...</div>);
}

// the rest of the component continues below
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support I find another solution

  const totalBalance =  clients &&clients.reduce((acc,client)=>parseFloat(acc + Number(client.balance)),0)